# Why does log4j work correctly on windows and Linux, the same configuration not working in docker?

Tags: docker, tomcat, log4j

I use tomcat as server and log4j can work on windows and Linux. When I deploy it with Docker, log4j can't work normally. And I find nothing is created in related folder. I don't find any error in catalina.log. I check the access rights for tmp folder and writing is allowed. Do you have any idea about source of the problem? Thanks.

```
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, DailyRolling, Terminal, CONSOLE
#log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, A1, A2, DailyRolling, Terminal, CONSOLE
log4j.appender.DailyRolling=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.DailyRolling.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.DailyRolling.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-7p (%c) %m%n
log4j.appender.DailyRolling.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd-a

#LINUX
log4j.appender.DailyRolling.File=/tmp/RolingLog.log
log4j.appender.DailyRolling.DatePattern=yyyy-MM-dd'.log'
log4j.appender.DailyRolling.Threshold=INFO
log4j.appender.DailyRolling.BufferedIO=true
log4j.appender.DailyRolling.BufferSize=8192
log4j.appender.DailyRolling.MaxFileSize=20MB
log4j.appender.DailyRolling.MaxBackupIndex=100
log4j.appender.DailyRolling.MaxBackupDay=10

log4j.appender.Terminal=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.Terminal.MaxBackupDay=10
#LINUX
log4j.appender.Terminal.File=/tmp/LogConsole.log
log4j.appender.Terminal.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.Terminal.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-7p (%c) %m%n

log4j.appender.CONSOLE=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.encoding=UTF-8
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.layout.conversionPattern=%d [%t] %-5p %c - %m%n

log4j.logger.httpclient.wire=INFO
log4j.logger.org.apache.commons=INFO
log4j.logger.org.hibernate=WARN
log4j.logger.org.oracle=INFO
log4j.logger.com.mchange.v2=INFO
log4j.logger.org.apache.commons.httpclient=WARN
log4j.logger.org.apache.xerces=ERROR
log4j.logger.org.springframework=INFO
```

Comment: you should probably describe how you configured Docker. Make the issue reproducible (see [mcve]), and the chances to get help will increase dramatically

Comment: Do you send the logs to an endpoint (in which case, did you enable the port of Docker to do so), or do you save the log locally (in which case, did you mount the path of the log into your container)?

Comment: I can create file in the folder by Java code. It should be mount.

Comment: I have solved it. I check the log of docker, find some issue related with log4j. After I add lib in pom.xml, it run well now(slf4j-simple, slf4j-jdk14, slf4j-nop).